# Android sliding layer how to force open

Tags: android, sliding, android-sliding

I'm doing android app it contains slider animation.

Animation working fine while clicking button but it should be open by default.

How to open [Sliding Layer](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib) by default.

my code:

```
SlidingLayer slideAnim = (SlidingLayer)findViewById(R.id.slidingLayer);

This is working only by click button not default
slideAnim.openLayer(true);
```

Thanks
Ramachandran.

Comment: What "Sliding Layer" are you using? Is it `DrawerLayout` or something else? Unless you explain **completely and precisely** what you are using, we cannot tell you how to use it in a way to have it be open by default.

Comment: What do you mean by `open by default.`. I didn't get your question. Please describe in brief.

Comment: After initialization openlayer(true) is not working.

Comment: There is no `SlidingLayer` in the Android SDK.

Comment: This is external lib check this link https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib

Comment: Seems like there is an open issue for that precise situation: https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib/issues/44 :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer! You have to put it in a Runnable!

```
slideAnim.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        slideAnim.openLayer(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Right, there's no such an opening state yet. Posting an "open" is the way to go as it won't get executed until the view is there. Opening the layer won't have any effect (or crash in the worst of cases) if the view is not yet there.